# Is there any legal syntax that would allow for a quotation mark to appear right next to an identifier character in javascript? (like"so")

Tags: javascript, c++

I'm trying to embed a .js file into a c++ project without using any of the compiler/platform specific resource tools while the .js file is still 100% valid javascript (as in you could plug it straight into a html document and it would run).

Currently I'm trying to figure out how to hide the raw string literal from js but no luck so far.

in loader.h I have:

```
#define var const char*
#include "test.js"
```

and in test.js

```
var my_js_source = R"###(";

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i, i);
}

alert("hey");

//)###";
```

It is the literal that is tripping me up, R"( in its most minimal form. Since I've found no way to hide it from js, I'm wondering if there is any syntax in js that would allow for R" to appear without being inside a string or a comment?

Doesn't matter if it can't execute as the first command as long as the syntax is valid since I can wrap it in a try block pretty easily.

Comment: Could you change the quotation mark in `test.js` to a backtick? If so, I may have a solution. A direct answer to "can an identifier be directly followed by a quotation mark" would be no.

Comment: @MikeC No :| it must be a double quote, also AFAIK the backtick is in the list of banned characters in most c++ compilers.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I think you're SOL. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

I managed to hide the raw string literal after all by using html style single line comment `<!--`, which, given some context is a valid sequence of operators in c++.

On the c++ side I have js_loader.h:

```
#pragma once
#define var bool
int js_loader_dummy_int = 1024;

// include js files here
#include "test.js"

#undef var
```

On the js side, each of the js files must contain special first and last lines. test.js:

```
var js_loader_dummy_bool_2935623962 = 1<!--js_loader_dummy_int; const char* test_js = R"###(


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
alert("hey");


//)###";
```

Both the names of the 2 variables declared on the first line must be unique.

The first line as interpreted by C++ creates a dummy boolean value and assigns the result of `1<!--js_loader_dummy_int` to it. Then creates a const char* and uses the raw string literal to capture the entire rest of the .js file.

When interpreted by js, it creates a dummy variable and assigns the value of 1 to it, then reaches the comment delimiter and ignores the rest.

The last line is commented out as far as js is concerned, for C++ it contains the end delimiter for the string literal.

So far I've tested this in MSVC, latest chrome and firefox without any problems.

Its not perfect though, some concerns:

1. As seen by js, the first statement doesn't end with a semicolon. Not sure what js specification has to say about it but the browsers don't seem to mind
2. Using a html style comment inside js. This has always worked AFAIK but again, not sure how well it goes with the js specification.